# Firebase ReferenceError: "getDatabaseByUrl" is not defined. (line 14, file "Code")

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Getting error when trying to GetDatabaseByURL - Here is my code. If anyone is able to let me know what the error is, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1iBbmL5crQGFWnQzACOzKhip-KSInd0lCu6za-I2TXzY");
var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B2')
var data = getFirebaseData('myArray')
Logger.log(data)
range.setValues(JSON.parse(data))
}

function getFirebaseData(data) {
var firebaseurl = 'https://ionafusion.firebaseio.com/'
var secret = 'LCOrPeYk4v4MTxb33pmErXjERdtAjdUakfBooSHd'
var base = getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseurl, secret);
var result = base.getData(data);
return result;
}
```

`Firebase ReferenceError: "getDatabaseByUrl" is not defined. (line 14, file "Code")`

Comment: Apparently you don't have a function called getDatabaseByUrl.  You'll need to define one that does what you want.

Comment: If you had already installed the library of FirebaseApp, you can use ``FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url, optSecret)``. If you had never installed it, you can see about the install at [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase). And the quickstart is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script).

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry, I appreciate your reply. I'm pretty new to these google scripts. Isn't getDatabaseByUrl part of the firebase library which I've added?
EDIT: Fixed. however I've encountered a new error.

Comment: I don't know - you haven't said what you've done to set up this code.

Comment: Alright, so I'm trying to push data from spreadsheets to firebase. I've tried your script using TS but I encountered this error src/index.ts(31,9): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ auth: any; spreadsheetId: string; range: string; valueInputOption: string; resource: { values: ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$UpdateValuesResponse>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'auth' does not exist in type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$UpdateValuesResponse>'.
src/index.ts(31,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AuthClient'.

Comment: I'm getting some kind of syntax error here - https://imgur.com/a/5iCtMcp

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry I probably should've tagged you.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you've done up to this point.  Comments are not especially easy to read, especially when it comes to code.

Comment: Alrighty will do